# Why SurfaceInkCanvas do not draw?

Tags: .net, wpf, pixelsense

I am trying to do a simple example to use the `SurfaceInkCanvas` but, it will not draw any thing when I try to use the touch over it, although `EditingMode="Ink"`

Here is the code:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="SurfaceApplication1.SurfaceWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    Title="SurfaceApplication1"
    >
  <Grid>
        <s:SurfaceInkCanvas x:Name="PostcardCanvas"
                                EditingMode="Ink"
                                Background="Orange"
                                Height="320"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                UsesTouchShape="False"
                                Width="426" />          
  </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

So, what's I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

to

```
IsHitTestVisible="True"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was that simple

Comment: You should read documentation for the properties before using them.